Assignment of binds via loop doesn't work
I've tried to modify my code and make the assignments of binding events and shortcut to function via loop.
it work by having a master dictionary (not necessary, just for "shortcut modes" preposes) and a sub-dictionary with the key as the event and the value as the function.
there is also some conditions for what to bind, if the event needs double chevrons and lastly if it's custom one that ends with a alphabetical character - make it bind event both with that character upper and lower.
this is the function:
from large_variables import * # this is where we get the the characters_str - a list of upper alphabetic characters
from tkinter import *

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ....
        self.binds('initial')

    def binds(self, mode : str):
    # modes dicts
        initial_dict = {'Modified' : self.status, 'Cut' : lambda event: self.cut(True), 'Copy' : self.copy(True), 'Control-Key-a' : self.select_all,
                        'Control-Key-l' : self.align_text, 'Control-Key-e' : lambda: self.align_text('center'), 'Control-Key-r' : lambda: self.align_text('right'),
                        'Control-Key-Delete' : self.clear, 'Alt-F4' : self.exit_app, 'Control-Key-plus' : self.sizes_shortcuts,
                        'Control-Key-minus' : self.sizes_shortcuts(-1), 'F5' : self.dt}
        auto_dict, autol_dict = {'KeyPress' : self.emoji_detection, 'KeyRelease' : self.update_insert_image_list}, {'KeyRelease': self.aul_var}
        typef_dict = {'Control-Key-b' : lambda e: self.typefaces(tf='bold'), 'Control-Key-i' : lambda e: self.typefaces(tf='italics'),
                      'Control-Key-u' : lambda e: self.typefaces(tf='underline')}
        editf_dict = {'Control-Key-f' : self.find_text, 'Control-Key-h' : self.replace, 'Control-Key-g' : self.goto}
        filea_dict = {'Control-Key-p' : self.print_file, 'Control-Key-n' : self.new_file, 'Alt-Key-d' : self.copy_file_path,
        'Control-o' : self.open_file, 'Control-Key-s' : self.save}
        textt_dict = {'Control-Shift-Key-j' : self.join_words, 'Control-Shift-Key-u' : self.lower_upper, 'Control-Shift-Key-r' : self.reverse_characters,
                      'Control-Shift-Key-c' : self.reverse_words}
        win_dict = {'F11' : self.full_screen, 'Control-Key-t' : self.topmost}

        # master dict
        bind_dict = {'initial' : initial_dict, 'autof' : auto_dict, 'typef' : typef_dict, 'editf' : editf_dict,
                     'filea' : filea_dict, 'textt' : textt_dict, 'windf' : win_dict, 'autol' : autol_dict}

        # specific mode or all
        if not(mode == 'initial' or mode == 'reset'):
            chosen_dict = bind_dict[mode]
        else:
            chosen_dict = {}
            for subdict in bind_dict.values():
                for key, value in subdict.items():
                    chosen_dict[key] = value

        for index, bond in enumerate(chosen_dict.items()):
            command, function = f'<{bond[0]}>', bond[1]
            bind_to = self
            if mode == 'auto':
                bind_to = self.EgonTE # bind to specific widget
            elif command == '<ComboboxSelected>':
                bind_to = self.font_size # bind to specific widget
                if index > 0:
                    bind_to = self.font_ui # bind to specific widget

            default_bind = True
            if command[-3] == '-' and command[-2].upper() in characters_str:
                bind_to.bind(f'{command[:-1]}{command[-1].upper()}', function) # condition for both last's char being in lower and upper case
            else:
                if not(command[-1].isdigit()): # condition for double chevrons 
                    bind_to.bind(f'<{command}>', function)
                    default_bind = False

            if default_bind: # mainly to complete the last's char being in lower and upper case
                bind_to.bind(command, function)

as you can see, also there's also modes to configure what to turn on (via another function there's unbinding and in here we bind again based on the chosen "mode") - but we don't need to take a look about that here - it won't change anything.
my problem is that although the code works fine and without errors and run smoothly when I test the shortcuts (binding) they do not work.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe code works without error but maybe it doesn't run some lines and this makes problem. OR maybe it assign event to wrong widget and it need to be focused to work. Maybe better create minimal reproducible example which we could simply copy and run.

@furas I fixed most of it, by fixing the slicing - I forgot to take into account the chevrons, and because it looked so completed I thought that TK have a problem with loops and local events
